# CGI scripts or other?

Tags: linux, ssh, script, python, cgi

So it is my first time writing scripts. Here is the scenario:

On our companies web server there are tools written in javascript that can verify user's accounts, change people passwords, and things like that. My job is to create a GUI so we can have non-technical people use these tools but not have to ssh into a linux box. I have the front-end pretty much done. I was thinking of using CGI scripts but then thought maybe it would be easier to script in javascript since the programs are in javascript as well so they may be easier to link? Or possibly I was thinking python since it is easier to pick up. Please let me know what is the best way you think to go about doing this is. Your help is much appreciated.

-cool_ruler

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: On apersonal note: Java seems to be on the way out, so that is one option I would not choose. As for the rest, everybody will have her or his own answer.

Comment: All the languages you mention will suffice! Do you know any? If so, use it! Otherwise, build a small application with each and see which suits you and your situation best?

Answer (score 0):

If you know and love JavaScript (no accounting for taste ;) ) why not use a JavaScript application framework for the back end? Something like [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) but there are [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks). The benefit of using a framework is if you select a good one, it will really teach you how to structure an application as well as take care of many tedious tasks for you.

But since you are open to the idea of learning another language, could I suggest Ruby? The reason I chose it initially was that Ruby code looked almost like my pseudocode. It's strong object-oriented philosophy has helped me understand OO programming better. There are also two huge benefits for what you're trying to do:

1. Ruby on Rails: hugely poplular application framework, most famously used to build Twitter. Loved by millions, ported to many languages.
2. [The Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org) One of the best programming books I've read, it is free on-line and constantly, almost obsesivelly, updated by its author. This will take you through building a web-app on Rails from scratch. It will include a functioning authentication system, so you can see if what you have is really up to the job.